# Ensure only valid input number format in Flutter TextField

Tags: flutter, double, textfield, inputformatter

I've got a TextField in my flutter app, for help inputting numbers for a calculator function. For this TextField, I have set the keyboard to be numbers only, using

`keyboardType: TextInputType.number`

Now, this works perfectly, in a sense that it ensures only the number input keyboard appears. This keyboard allows the user to input numbers from 0 to 9, as well as a decimal point. The problem is, it doesn't stop users inputting multiple decimal points. Once a user adds more than one, it makes the number invalid and the calculator doesn't work.

Essentially, what I need to do is ensure the user can only input 1 decimal point and digits, but no other characters.

I came across the `inputFormatters` feature on another question on this forum and I've tried to use it like so:

```
TextField(
 inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
      FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[0-9].")),
  ], // Only numbers and a decimal point can be entered
),
```

Whilst this does help to ensure only digits and decimal points are entered, it doesn't stop multiple decimal points being entered, when only one should be.

How can I edit this filtering rule, or what else can I do, to ensure only 1 decimal point can be entered, to ensure a number is always in the correct format (i.e. is always an integer or double)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried using `DecimalTextInputFormatter` input formatter?

```
TextFormField(
  inputFormatters: [DecimalTextInputFormatter(decimalRange: 1)],
  keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
)
```

You can achieve the same result using a regular expression along with `FilteringTextInputFormatter` (following your approach) like:

```
FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^\d+\.?\d{0,1}')),
```

The range `{0,1}` does the trick.

`RegExp(r'^\d+\.?\d?')` is also a valid expression for this case.

### Update (April 2024)

Same result can be achieved using directly `FilteringTextInputFormatters` via:

```
FilteringTextInputFormatters.numbersOnly
```

Comment: I hadn't actually thought of trying the `DecimalTextInputFormatter` input formatter, although I have modified my RegExp expression to be like yours and it seems to work perfectly, thanks!

Comment: This regex can be simplified to `FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^\d+\.?\d?'))`